# Regex negative lookahead ignore section of code

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation

I have some regex that finds a section of code in xml. However, I want it to ignore a section of code with a particular tag set In the middle.im using notepad++.
Below is a simplified version of my code.

```
</Question>
ABC
123
<answer>

</Question>
ABC
<Question>
123
<answer>
```

My regex picks up both groups but I want it to ignore the second group because of the tag

Here is the regex I’ve tried.

```
(?s-i)<\/Question>(?:(?!\<Question>)).*(<answer>)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore the second group, you should not cross matching `<Question>` or `</Question>`.

As the dot matches every character including a newline due to the `(?s)` the `.*` will match till the end of the line and will then backtrack to match `<answer>` matching all lines.

You can match a single char and then check what is directly to the right is not `<Question>` or `</Question>` and make the `/` optional.

You might use

```
(?s-i)</Question>(?:(?!</?Question>).)*<answer>
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?s-i)` Inline modifiers, dot matches a newline and turn off case insensitive matching
- `</Question>` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not

    - `</?Question>` Match either `</Question>` or  as the `?` matches 0 or 1 times
  - `).` If the assertion it true, match a single any character
- `)*` Close the group and optionally repeat
- `<answer>`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FvLfAh/1)

[image]

Comment: Awesome that works!  So the ?question looks just for the q and then the . looks at the rest of the word?  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Acme1235 I have added a breakdown of the pattern with a description of the different parts. The question mark makes the `/` optional.